# Logical error in Jquery or syntax?

Tags: jquery, html

One of the options by clicking the radio, was to show the same number of option dates, changing the display or none "" the corresponding tables, but this is not happening. You have an error in logic or syntax?

```
<style>
  #ch2   ,#ch3   ,#ch4   ,#ch5   ,#ch6   ,#ch7   ,#ch8   ,#ch9   ,#ch10  ,#ch11  ,#ch12{
        display: none;
  }

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        $("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
                var valor = $(this).val();
                for(i=1;i<=valor;i++){
                        $('#ch'+i).css("display","");
                }
                for(j=1;i<=12;i++){
                        $('#ch'+i).css("display","none");
                }

        })
});
</script>
<form name="senddata" method="post" action="">
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="radios" style="display: none">
        <tr>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="1" />1X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="2" />2X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="3" />3X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="4" />4X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="5" />5X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="6" />6X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="7" />7X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="8" />8X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="9" />9X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="10" />10X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="11" />11X</label></td>
                <td><label><input type="radio" name="parcelas" value="12" />12X</label></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch1">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data1"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch2">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data2"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch3">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data3"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch4">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data4"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch5">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data5"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch6">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data6"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch7">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data7"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch8">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data8"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch9">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data9"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch10">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data10"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch11">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data11"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table width="100%" border="0" id="ch12">
        <tr>
                <td>Data<br /><input name="input" type="text" name="data12"/></td>                
        </tr>
        </table>
</form>
```

Comment: Looking at your stylesheet -- you do know that's what classes are for, right?

Comment: You're asking us if there's a syntax error? Browsers have a console for displaying such things (e.g. shift-ctrl-J in firefox/chrome). You should check that yourself.

Comment: you are comparing a number `i` to a string `valor`. convert it to a number.

Comment: In the second `for` loop you should use `j` instead of `i`: `for (var j = 1; j <= 12; j++) { ... }`.

Comment: @VisioN ... or `i` instead of `j`.

Comment: The j I use is just to write correctly, because they do not want to set an initial value for the i, I want him to stay with the amount left is the earlier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for(i = 1; i <= valor; i++){
  $('#ch'+i).css("display","block"); // or inline but not left empty string
}
// here not j=1 and here you mix with j and i
for(j = valor+1; j <= 12; j++){
  $('#ch'+i).css("display","none");
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `display` be set to `block` or `inline` instead of an empty string?

Answer (score 0):

Simply specify a value instead of nothing:

```
$('#ch'+i).css("display","table");
```

That should do the trick, try it on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KPP42/).